# Make one of two sitecore content fields required?

Tags: content-editor, validation

I've been trying to find a way to make one of two fields valid and haven't come up with much.  Is there a way to do this with custom field validators or is that just relevant to individual fields?  The requirement is that one of two fields must be filled in, probably only one, but even if that's not possible, just having at least one filled in (and then there being a default in terms of which is used) would be acceptable, I suppose.

Comment: Nothing OOTB, but there may be a way to achieve what you are looking for via breaking up your content appropriately into different templates.

For example, if you have two datasource templates, you could have different rules for validation. The author picks which template they want to use by selecting compatible renderings. It may help to know more about your specific authoring scenario to help guide you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend implementing a custom **Item** validation rule.

> Note: This is different from a field validation, in that it validates *the entire item* instead of a single field.

## 1. Create custom validator

Create a new class that implements the `Sitecore.Data.Validators.StandardValidator` base class. In the `Evaluate()` method, get both fields and check to see if either of them has a value:

```
public class AtLeastOneFieldPopulatedValidator : StandardValidator
{
    public override string Name => "At Least One Field Populated";

    public AtLeastOneFieldPopulatedValidator() {}

    public AtLeastOneFieldPopulatedValidator(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) {}

    protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
    {
        Item item = base.GetItem();
        if (item == null)
        {
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["Field 1"]) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["Field 2"]))
        {
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }
        return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.CriticalError);
    }

    protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
    {
        return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
    }
}
```

## 2. Create `Validation Rule` item

First, create a new `Validation Rule` (template `/sitecore/templates/System/Validation/Validation Rule`) item somewhere below this node:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Item Rules`

[image: item validator tree]

> Important: Make sure you populate the `Type` field with your fully-qualified name of your custom validator's class (e.g. `Custom.Services.AtLeastOneFieldPopulatedValidator, Custom.Services`).

## 3. Associate your `Validation Rule` to your items

On the `__Standard values` of your item's template, show Standard Fields (View ribbon tab -> Standard fields) and add your `Validation Rule` to the appropriate validation fields. I recommend including it in all four.

## (Optional) Extra credit: Add parameters

I've not tested this, but I'm sure there's a way to pass parameters using the `Parameters` field on the `Validation Rule` item. In these parameters, you could pass a list of the fields to check so your validator can be reused by creating multiple `Validation Rule` items in Sitecore.

[image: parameters field]

Comment: did you test this code? It would be great if it works but my understanding is that item["Field 2"] would not have a value at the point the validation for item["Field 1"] fires. This is mentioned in the SSE posts I've referenced in my answer.

Comment: I believe this will be different, however, because this is an _Item_ validator (not a field validator). I believe it still runs after every field is updated (I haven't dug through the CE JS to verify that), but it validates the entire item instead of just a single field.

Comment: It also appears this is the same solution they used in the second SSE post you linked: "We additionally put an item validator on the component itself to prevent it from going through workflow."

Comment: Ahr right, sorry yes it's not a field validator so the values should both be set. No worries then.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge you point out a valid concern, though, that it was not clear. I've edited the answer to attempt to call that out more clearly.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but I can't see anything happening when I hit save, it just saves without any message.  I've created a class as you suggest and even just made it always return a failure, just to make sure I wasn't missing something.  But despite referencing it in the type field of the validator and including the custom validator for all the different standard values items in the template, it still does nothing. What else might I be missing?

Comment: Does your `Validation Rule` appear in the Validation fields on the item that you're trying to save?

Comment: No, for some reason it's not showing these rules in the item even though they are in the standard values of the template.. It seems it was a combination of this and the fact that I was saving as an admin user, when I downgraded it would not let me save the item once I manually inserted the validators in the validation section of the item and saved it (as admin).  So now I'm trying to understand why these validator references aren't showing up when I create a new item from that template???

Comment: Finally figured out that the issue was that I had the validation rules on the template item rather than on it's standard values item.  Ok, so now I just need to know if there's a way to have a custom message other than the default "Some of the fields in this item contain fatal errors" in order to give the user a clue what they need to do... ok seems like that's not possible without overiding the validation pipeline, which I don't want to do.  How would you recommend alerting the user to how they can fix the issue?

Comment: @LeviWallach - That's a good question, but it should be its own question. Go ahead and submit one and hopefully someone's got a good answer!

Comment: @LeviWallach - Also, if this is the solution you went with, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to implement this again but intellisense is telling me that UrlCharacterValidator method needs to have a return type?

Comment: @LeviWallach - Sorry about that, I had a typo in the class. It should not say `UrlCharacterValidator `, it should be `AtLeastOneFieldPopulatedValidator`. (I've edited the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box that will do this for you as far as I am aware and although you think it might be possible custom validation I don't think it is as the a validator works on only one field at a time so updates to the item would only have the updated data for that single field and not the other field. Therefore I think your only option here might be to use the `item:saving` event to validate the data there as mentioned by Richard Seal below:

[Item validator access already stored data instead of newly inputed data](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/item-validator-access-already-stored-data-instead-of-newly-inputed-data)

You need to be careful with this though to make sure it doesn't fire all of the time. Maybe you could check the template before running this validation or something.

Another related thread on SSE is here:
[Apply field validations across fields](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/apply-field-validations-across-fields)

Comment: Yeah, talking to another developer we already it seems have a custom validator that's doing something via the item:saving event, so I should be able to just tack this additional validation on to it.  Thanks for helping me pinpoint the issue and solution.

Comment: No worries. I come across these kind of scenarios now and again and sometimes you can just handle the display logic in the controller before rendering and through Content Editor education. It would be useful if we could do this more easily with Custom Validators though.